# Blind Copy sending doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook

Next code doesn't work properly but it doesn't crash at all.

```
MailAddress addressTo = new MailAddress("to@someone.com");
MailAddress addressFrom = new MailAddress("from@someone.com");
MailAddress addressBCC = new MailAddress("bcc@someone.com");
MailAddress addressBCC2 = new MailAddress("bcc2@someone.com");
MailMessage MyMessage = new MailMessage(addressFrom, addressTo);
MyMessage.Bcc.Add(addressBCC);
MyMessage.Bcc.Add(addressBCC2);
```

It sends the mail to "to@someone.com" and "bcc@someone.com" but "bcc2@someone.com" is not receiving anything.

Is there any problem with several addresses in BCC list?

Comment: It looks like SMTP issue. You can check smtp server log to ensure that you have no limits to bcc adresses or other problem.

Comment: What if you first add "BBC2" and then "BBC", is it still the first that arrives (now BBC2), or is it an issue with the "BBC2" address?

Comment: then only BBC2 is arriving.
Sorry I have no access to SMTP server at all just credentials to connect as sender to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an smtp server's Issue, after fixing a bug on it the code written above began to work perfectly.